# mvc3 how can I put a number on lower part of an image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image

I have been stumped, I am trying to find a way to put a user ID number on the lower left corner of the image is there a way I can do this? to illustrate this is what I have so far

```
foreach (var item in Model.profile)
{ 
 // user picture
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/uploads/profilepic" + item.photo)"   alt="" />
  // user id number
   @Html.ActionLink(@item.userID, "user", "profile",new { id = item.ProfileID })
    }
```

With the code above the user ID number appears next to the image but I am trying to get it inside the image maybe lower-left or right corner.. I been searching for a solution for a few hours can anyone give some suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved using css. First wrap the actionlink in a div.

```
foreach (var item in Model.profile)
{ 
  // user picture
  <img src="@Url.Content("~/uploads/profilepic" + item.photo)"   alt="" />
  // user id number
  <div class="imageLabel">
    @Html.ActionLink(@item.userID, "user", "profile",new { id = item.ProfileID })
  </div>
}
```

Then the css:

```
.imageLabel {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

This will take your actionlink and move it 20 pixels above it's initial position which should be on the image.